# Need superuser permission for TMS

Tags: root-access, sync, external-sd, superuser

for some cloud syncing purposes I want to give TMS (Titanium Media Sync) superuser privilege over my rooted device even if it doesn't asks for it.

I use SuperSU.

Comment: Have you tried seeing if TMC is dotted in the SuperSU logs?

Comment: Umm... TMS is not a root app, it will not ask for root access because it doesn't use it. You can't give an app "superuser privilege", it has to request it.

Comment: DanB: I've only checked the list of apps SuperSu manages, and TMS isn't listed.         acejavelin: Oh! that's a shame! I thought there would be an option like in linux to run an app with superuser privilege. similar to "sudo"...